# Firebase custom sound notification with Xamrin Forms works with IOS but doesn't work with android when app is not running

Tags: android, .net, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've searched everywhere and tried many solutions with no luck. I am using an API to send notifications to my app ( Android / IOS) with a custom sound file that is already included in my app files. the sound works fine for IOS even if the app is closed but it doesn't work for Android until the app is working on the background.
 here is the JSON which I use

```
{
  to = deviceId,
  priority = "high",
  content_available = true,
  notification = new
   {
   body = englishMessage,
   title = title,
   badge = 1,
   content_available = true
   },
   android = new
    {
    ttl="86400s",
    priority= "high",
    notification = new
     {
      sound = SoundFileName,
     },
    },
     apns = new
     {
      payload = new
      {
       aps = new
       {
        sound = SoundFileName,
        content_available = true,
        badge = 1,
       },
      },
      customKey = "test app",
     }
  }
```

Comment: Did the notification display on the screen on android when the app is in background ? Or did you try to use the default sound ?

Comment: Hi  Lucas Zhang - MSFT, yes it displays on screen, I only face issue with custom sound

Comment: You could post the issue to google official forums .

Answer (score 0):

When your app is in the foreground the notification is manually generated by you which means you need to manually add this sound to your notification, so what you do is something like

```
var soundUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(pathToPushSound);
```

And then in the notification manager add the following method

```
     var notiManager= Notification.Builder(context)
                                  .SetSound(soundUri) ...
```

Comment: Hi @FreakyAli, thank you so much for your answer, yea when the app is working on background I can play any sound, but what I really need is to play custom sound when the app is closed. I can do this in IOS, but in android it doesn't work

Comment: When your app is in killed state?

Comment: yes exactly, currently on IOS when I send notification I can play a custom sound from api, but I cannot do it on Android

Comment: Did you try setting the sound from the notification channel?

Comment: I am talking about the notification channel android not the json : https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Comment: yes I am using the notification channel, it plays the custom sound perfectly but it works only when the app is running, (background/foreground) but it doesn't play the custom sound when the app is killed